# DDD tactical design for a lesson booking system, too many aggregate roots?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

suppose to have an domain where you can book either private lessons with a teacher, or apply to a specific collective course.
Every course has its own pricelist, but the pricelist for the private lessons is the same for every teacher, but changes based on the period of the year, and the time of day.
When you book either a private lesson or a course you can buy/book some other generic item, as for example a gadget or maybe the lunch for the duration of the booking (i.e. a week). Every single course maintains a list of allowed items to be booked/bought. For the private lessons we have a list of allowed items too, but it’s fixed for any private lesson (red sticky here….)
So far I identified 4 aggregates:

- Courses
- Items
- Teachers
- PrivateLessonsPricelist

I pretty new to DDD, but I feel like in this case 4 aggregates are too much, and the model should be simplified. Can anyone more experienced give me their opinion?
Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking for a conversation about a design, you should perhaps consider the ddd-cqrs-es discord: https://discord.gg/sEZGSHNNbH

Comment: Thank you so much! I was actually looking for a ddd related group on discord, but couldn't find one. I'll surely join!

Comment: You should include the features for each of your aggregate to help answer the why.